# Is the Fear & Loathing hat likely to encourage harmful behavior?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

[The criteria for earning the Fear & Loathing hat is:](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/fear--loathing)

> Delete own answer

I'm concerned this could potentially encourage users to post a nonsense answer and then delete it to get a hat. [Unlike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/36/peer-pressure) [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined), hats are transient - it's possible users may put less thought into their actions as a result.

Is this fear warranted? And if so how could such behavior be discouraged?

Comment: You know there are *two* different badges for this, right?

Answer (score 7):

Nothing says it has to ***stay*** deleted.

Comment: To me, this sounds even worse - too many users may "game" this aspect, post an answer, delete it to get the hat, and then undelete it go get their rep back. How is this beneficial to the community?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to delete a recent answer.

Deleting an old, downvoted answer counts just as much as deleting an answer you just posted. I happened to have exactly one answer at -1 on Super User, and the system awarded me the *Fear & Loathing* hat when I deleted it.

Comment: Quick! Everybody go undelete that one! Maybe there’s a secret hat underneath!!

Answer (score 2):

no one would ever do that..... well, yea, they/I would. Is that against the rules? Answers that are deleted count against you in the answer block system. So it does technically hurt the user too. So it's not the wisest thing to do.

Ok, so I might not delete this answer as I was planning. I did however delete an old -1 score answer I had on Stack Overflow. I got the Fear and Loathing hat for deleting it. So you can get this hat for deleting any of your answers, it doesn't have to be an answer you posted during Winter bash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's hard for someone with an established account to get answer banned. Personally I have over 200 deleted answers. I could delete another one and nobody would know/care.

Comment: saying "no one would ever do that" seems kind of a stretch to me. Are you that sure NO user on the site would do that for a hat?

Comment: It's a hat, not a badge.